# Does Apple's PencilKit support that Drawing and Holding to Create Perfect Shapes, if not, how to implement it?

Tags: ios, swift, drawing, pencilkit

What I want:

[image]

The picture is from `Notes` app in iPad. The blurred red path I drew with Apple Pencil. Holding and then the perfect circle shape generated.

I checked the Apple's developer documentation about PencilKit. It seems no related API to support it.

But apple's `Notes` app of the system in iPad can do it. Does it mean that Apple have not opened the relevant API? However, I really need to implement Drawing and Holding to Create Perfect Shapes in our app. How to do it?

The only thing I can think of is to use coreML to reshape pencil path? I know very little about it.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Comment: I haven't implemented it, but I suppose it needs to be solved by machine learning, in which by building a huge dataset that containing a lot of `CGPoints`(x(i)) and Perfect Shape type(y(i)) values, then training it uses logistic regression which is a classification method.  And  I'm learning machine learning. Hope to do it!